# Pyproj switching output coordinates

Tags: python, pyproj

I'm trying to project from ED50 31N to WGS 84. I'm using script below but when I generate the outputs they are inverted from the coordinates I would expect. I expect `x_out` to be `4.031819616199967` and `y_out` to be `58.63423101793458` and not vice-versa (what python returns for me). I'm running this with pyproj 2.6.1. When I use an online converter (e.g. https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=23031&t_srs=4326&x=560000.0000000&y=6500000.0000000) I do get the expected coordinates. Any idea why they are inverted with this script?

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from pyproj import Transformer
>>> in_EPSG = 'epsg:23031'
>>> out_EPSG = 'epsg:4326'
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs(in_EPSG, out_EPSG)

>>> x_in = 560000
>>> y_in = 6500000
>>> x_out,y_out = transformer.transform(x_in,y_in)

>>> print(x_out)
58.63423101793458
>>> print(y_out)
4.031819616199967
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running into axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6

This should restore the expected order:

```py
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(in_EPSG, out_EPSG, always_xy=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!